# Red Hat internal specifications

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel

I'm doing a homework assignment for my college, and I'm trying to find the parameters used in kernel compilation on RedHat.

My teacher asks: "Analyse and describes in terms of models of each version of linux for Servers: process, scheduling, memory management, file system, security"

I can't find anything on RedHat documentation (what I found was too brief).

I searched the entire RedHat website and I couldn't find it, can someone give me a pointer?

Comment: You can usually find the kernel configs for installed kernels in `/boot`.

Answer (score 3):

The most common way is `zcat /proc/config.gz`, that should get your the configuration for the running kernel.

You may also checkout the source RPMS of `kernel-X` package, where you can find configuration of other architectures as well

Comment: uhm, i think its not what i need, dont have documentation? i tryied to find on redhat website but i failed.

Comment: @MatheusSilva Read this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779332/how-to-download-the-source-code-for-redhat-linux-enterprise-kernel-2-6-18-128-el it should get you a hint on source code & documentation

Comment: `/proc/config.gz` isn't usually compiled in on RHEL kernels. (Look in `/boot` for the `config-*` files instead -- why take up memory when a static file will do?

Comment: @MatheusSilva If this answer -- the direct, actual kernel parameters used! -- doesn't provide you what you need to know for your homework, then you need to clarify further what your homework actually asks.

Comment: @mattdm updated my question, maybe i clarified what i want.

Comment: That's a pretty big question!

Comment: @mattdm i absolutely search in all the internet!